# Can you name an instance of w3wp.exe so it shows up in attach to process?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I run multiple processes under IIS and when debugging it can be tough to know which process I want to attach to.  Can you programatically set the "Title" of a process so that it can be identified in Visual Studio's "Attach to Process" window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS 7.5 you IIS will automatically create accounts for each appPool with the name of the application pool.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Answer (score 2):

Might be better to change the [identity](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f05a7c2b-36b0-4b6e-ac7c-662700081f25.mspx?mfr=true) of the process so that you know which one to attach to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this VS macro to attach to a worker process based on the application name.  The only trick is you need to copy Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv to %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.

```
Private Sub AttachToWorkerProcess(ByVal appName As String)
    Dim targetPid = FindPoolPIDByName(appName)
    If targetPid = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to find a worker process hosting " + appName)
    End If

    Dim processes As EnvDTE.Processes = DTE.Debugger.LocalProcesses

    For Each proc As EnvDTE.Process In processes
        If proc.ProcessID = targetPid Then
            proc.Attach()
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Function FindPoolPIDByName(ByVal appName As String) As Integer
    Dim sm As New Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager()

    Dim appPoolName As String = Nothing
    For Each site In sm.Sites
        For Each app In site.Applications
            If String.Equals(app.Path, "/" & appName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                appPoolName = app.ApplicationPoolName
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If appPoolName Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to find application " & appName)
    End If

    For Each wp In sm.WorkerProcesses
        If wp.AppPoolName = appPoolName Then
            Return wp.ProcessId
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

Then:

```
Sub AttachToMyApp()
     AttachToWorkerProcess("MyApp")
End Sub
```